# What happens if I power a 12 V LED lamp at twice its voltage with a 24 V power supply?

Tags: lamp

If I have an LED lamp which is specified as, say, 350 mA at 12 V DC, what would happen if I fed it directly from a 48 V DC constant-current power supply capable of providing up to 350 mA?

I understand increasing the voltage on an LED lamp typically makes it run hotter as it tries to draw more current, but since it is fed by a current limited source is this issue voided?

Edit: I am talking about higher-powered LED lamps, like ones used for outdoor lighting such as streetlights, garden lights, etc. Say a maximum wattage of 30 W.

Comment: What exactly is this "LED"?  LEDs have a forward voltage of 1-3V or so; you're probably talking about an assembly of LEDs with resistors and that is important for understanding how it will work.

Comment: Are you talking about bare string of LEDs, or LED string with a resistor, or lamps with built-in CC driver?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because I have no idea what you're asking.  You want to power a 4W power supply off of 48V to run a 30W high power outdoor light?  That can't be right since it obviously won't work.  Edit your question to explain what light you have and what you want to do with it.

Comment: `48VDC constant current power supply providing 350mA` would not necessarily output 48 V ... it would output a voltage that is necessary to push 350 mA through the load

Comment: A constant current driver will generally have a range of voltages that it can work at (which should be specified on the label). So 48V nominal might be something like 40V~50V 350mA CC. You have to see if that range will accomodate your 12V needs.

Comment: It would get confused about 24 V (title) or 48 V (body).

Comment: @jsotola so the voltage level would drop to levels of say 12v etc.? Does this introduce any danger in the cc device?

Comment: no, it would not drop, because it should not ride to a higher voltage in the first place ... of course, that depends on the power supply design

Comment: say the source is a 48V bus from a standard industry down converter such as meanwell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a constant current driver, it will drive the LED with constant current and the LED voltage ends up being 12V or whatever it happens to be with the LED.

So the output voltage to LED must be identical with identical current, the output voltage from CC driver can't be any higher or different, or a different amount of current would flow.

Another thing is, does the constant current driver support 12V LEDs or not. It depends on the output range it requires to operate properly.

Comment: Not sure I understand you here. I want to say remove the LED Driver completely from the equation. Just red and black into the LED itself (say a street lamp). The LED Driver spec is 12V at 350mA. Instead, if I feed 48V into the red black of the LED - via a current limited source at 350mA will the LED light and/or would it be dangerous/cause damage?

Comment: @BrandonKellett I don't understand what you want. You say "remove the LED driver" which will have been a constant current device. Then you say "feed 48V into the red black of the LED - via a current limited source" which is exactly what you started with. Without current limiting, applying 48V to a 12V LED will instantly destroy it.

Comment: You said you have a LED. That means bare LED with no CC driver. If you mean a complete system which already has a CC driver which takes in 350mA at 12V then edit that into question. And putting two CC drivers in series will most likely be a bad idea. If you want to drive a lamp which has a CC driver that takes in 12V, then you just need a 24V to 12V power supply, not a second CC driver to power the original CC driver.

Comment: LED is driving by current. 12V/350mA means your device has resistors inside or some kind of driver. External source of 350mA will not damage your device.

Comment: @PeterJennings let me explain. I was contemplating removing the 12vdc cc device, because if I can use the 48vdc bus direct with a current limitation, it means I increase the energy of my system by removing a dc/dc conversion. From reading another answer you supplied on a seperate thread you stated: "It is not possilbe to have the correct current through an LED, but too high a voltage across it." So, if the current is limited to say 350mA - does this statement not hold true?

Comment: If you remove the original CC driver and put another CC driver, it depends on the type of new CC driver, if it has a DC-DC switch mode circuit or linear current limiter. The former has roughly speaking 90% efficiency, and the linear/resistor one has to waste all excess power as heat.

Comment: And what about the voltage level @Justme? Due to the higher voltage level, and with power being voltage times current - does this increase in power mean that the LED will 'blow' or overheat. Or does the current limiting itself solve this?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on what type of LED driver it is, if any. We can't know if it is a switch mode power supply or linear or just a resistor. So we can't know what input voltage range it supports and what output voltage range it supports for driving the bare LEDs.

Comment: "*Due to the higher voltage level, and with power being voltage times current - does this increase in power mean that the LED will 'blow' or overheat. Or does the current limiting itself solve this?*" The constant current driver reduces the voltage across the LED to the correct level. You multiply **that voltage** by the current to get the power, not the 48 V supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

That is a "lamp" not an "LED". Yes, it uses LEDs inside it, but it also has electronic components to limit the current. Therefore, the answer is not straight forward because it depends on what those electronic components do:

I see these possibilities:

- It uses resistors: at 48 V the current would increase, possibly 10-fold; the supply is current limited to 350 mA; the result is that its output would stay at 12 V; therefore, no change
- It uses resistors: at 48 V the current would increase, possibly 10-fold; the supply is current limited to more than 350 mA, say 500 mA;  the result is that its output would go up to, say, 14 V; therefore, the lamp would be brighter; at least for a while
- It uses resistors: at 48 V the current would increase, possibly 10-fold; the supply is current limited to more than 350 mA, say 500 mA;  the result is that its output would go up to, say, 14 V; therefore, the lamp would be brighter but it can't handle it; it blows up: no light
- It uses resistors: at 48 V the current would increase, possibly 10-fold; the supply is not current limited and it blows up: no light
- It uses a current source: it that can handle 48 V; the LED would still see the same current: no change
- It uses a current source: it that can handle 48 V but not the heat; the LED would still see the same current; after a while, the current source overheats and blows up: no light
- It uses a current source: it that cannot handle 48 V; it blows up: no light

In summary, the most likely result is that either the power supply or the lamp blows up.

Answer (score 0):

> *I understand increasing the voltage on an LED typically makes it run
> hotter as it tries to draw more current, but if it is fed by a current
> limited source is this issue voided?*

Not only will it run hotter, it is likely to burn the LED and destroy it. A 350 mA constant current supply does what it says on the tin; it provides the current required by the LED (if 350 mA is what the LED specification indicates).

Comment: If the current is limited, what then generates the heat // causes the damage to destroy it?

Comment: Heat will still be generated even when the current is limited. Some LEDs need heatsinking to remove that heat or they'll also burn-out. @BrandonKellett

Comment: Sure, so if say the LED is mounted in an aluminium frame (similar to say a street light) then this would be fine? All I am trying to do is increase the efficiency of my system and remove a dc/dc conversion

Comment: LEDs need to have over-current protection. Call it current limiting or constant current if you will. This can be made from a regulated DC voltage and a resistor (lossy) or it can be made from a DC/DC converter that provides a constant current and, this method can be more energy efficient. So, removing the DC/DC converter is likely to require a resistor to limit the current and, this will be less efficient @BrandonKellett

Comment: Are there other forms of current limiting aside from the regulator/resistor method that would enchance this then? Or is this a losing battle to fight? The DC/DC converter will waste say 10% of the power due to inefficiencies, would the resistor/regulator method consume more? Or another form of regulator?

Comment: A DC/DC is probably your best bet though it might waste 5% to 7% if designed correctly and more if designed incorrectly @BrandonKellett